# Exporting video is always fail

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to compound video with recorded voice. so i make such a code

```
func saveMediaCompaundWithMovie(videoAsset: AVAsset) {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "mov")!)
    let videoAsset = AVAsset(URL: url)

    let mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let videoCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let videoAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first
    let range = CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: videoAssetTrack!.timeRange.duration)
    do { try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(range, ofTrack: videoAssetTrack!, atTime: kCMTimeZero) } catch {}
    let videoSize = videoAssetTrack?.naturalSize

    let audioCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let audioAsset = AVAsset(URL: self.recorder.url)  //MARK: self.recorder.url is voice data.And I checked this data is correctly played.
    let audioAssetTrack = audioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio).first
    let maxDuration = audioAssetTrack!.timeRange.duration
    do { try audioCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(range, ofTrack: audioAssetTrack!, atTime: kCMTimeZero) } catch {}

    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    let documents = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentationDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0].path
    let fileName = NSURL(string: documents!)?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("compound").URLByAppendingPathExtension("mov")
    exporter?.outputURL = fileName

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: maxDuration)
    let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComp.renderSize = videoSize!
    videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    videoComp.instructions = [instruction]

    exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter?.videoComposition = videoComp
    exporter?.timeRange = range
    exporter?.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({ () -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            switch (exporter!.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed:
                print("suceed to save")
                break
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
                print("canceled")
                break
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
                print("failed")
                print(exporter?.error?.localizedDescription)
                print(exporter?.error?.userInfo.description)
                print(exporter?.error?.localizedFailureReason)
                print(exporter?.error?.localizedRecoverySuggestion)
                break
            default:
                break;
            }
        })
    })

}
```

then always AVAssetExportSessionStatus is fail. console log is like that

```
failed
Optional("Operation Stopped")
Optional("[NSLocalizedDescription: Operation Stopped,          NSLocalizedFailureReason: The video could not be composed.]")
Optional("The video could not be composed.")
```

Could anybody notice wrong part?I hope your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Catch the errors instead of ignoring them. Replace `catch {}` with actual error handling. Then you will know *why* it doesn't work. And if not, it will help debugging anyway.

Comment: Thanks, comment. I modified my code like this.       
 `do { try audioCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(range, ofTrack: audioAssetTrack!, atTime: kCMTimeZero) } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }`
but it hasn't catched the error.

Comment: It's already a good step forward: now you know what parts of the code *don't* crash. That makes less code to inspect to look for the crash source.

Comment: Now a good debug would be to check if the assets are properly exportable and composable by checking their `exportable` and `composable` [properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAsset/playable), for example, among other things.

Comment: I have just checked exportable and composable property of videoAsset and audioAsset.Then, Both of them are true. and this time, error log is different one. `Optional("The operation could not be completed") Optional("[NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12105 \"(null)\", NSLocalizedFailureReason: An unknown error occurred (-12105), NSLocalizedDescription: The operation could not be completed]") Optional("An unknown error occurred (-12105)")`

Comment: Yes, I've seen your comment, but I can't find what this error number means.

Comment: ok, i will continue to debugging. anyway thanks many comment! @EricD.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line

```
let fileName = NSURL(string: documents!)?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("compound").URLByAppendingPathExtension("mov")
```

with this

```
let fileName = URL(fileURLWithPath: (documents?.appending("/compound.MOV"))!)
```

I was having the same problem. Setting the output URL this way got it working. not sure about the underlying cause though.